# Avoid key violation on insert in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, primary-key

I'm using Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a situation where I would like to insert a record whos primary key fields *might* match an existing record. Rather than raise and error, I'd like to have the existing record silently updated with the new data.

My current implementation is something like this:

```
// Calculate primary key fields.
DateTime endDate = periodTime.AddMinutes(periodMins);
int meterId = pipe.MeterId;

// Try to load a matching record.
ProfileDatum lpRec = context.ProfileData.FirstOrDefault(rec => rec.MeterId == meterId && rec.EndDate == endDate);
// If it could not be loaded, create a new one.
if (lpRec == null)
{
    lpRec = new ProfileDatum() {MeterId = meterId,
                                EndDate = endDate};

    // Save the object in the context.
    context.ProfileData.AddObject(lpRec);
}

// Fill lpRec.
```

This works, but it's pretty awful in efficiency, readability and elegance.

Sticking with the Entity Framework and SQL Server 2008 R2, is there any way to do something like MySQL's "on duplicate key update" where I proceed as if creating a new record each time and have the database update when there's a primary key violation? Or perhaps there is there some other elegant approach?

Efficiency is nice but secondary in this case; it's simplicity I'm after. It would be great to be able 
to write it as follows and omit client-side checking:

```
// Assign primary key fields.
var lpRec = new ProfileDatum()
{
    MeterId = pipe.MeterId,
    EndDate = periodTime.AddMinutes(periodMins)
};

// Fill lpRec.

// Save the object in the context.
context.ProfileData.AddObject(lpRec);
```

Thanks in advance for any help, even if it's to say that my existing implementation is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use ObjectContext.GetObjectByKey/TryGetObjectByKey?

According to the msdn help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738728.aspx

TryGetObjectByKey will first look at the list of loaded objects,  If object is not there, it will attempt to load it from the store by PK.  If the load fails (it's not in the db), then TryGetObjectByKey will return false (GetObjectByKey will throw)

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entityKeyValues =
  new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
  {
    new KeyValuePair<string, object> ("MeterId", meterId);
  }

  EntityKey key = new EntityKey("YourContainerName.YourEntitySetName", entityKeyValues);
  object entity = null;
  if(context.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out entity))
  {
     //the entity exists either in memory, or in the db
  }
  else
  {
     // you need to insert a new one
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, letting it happen in the DB is going to be your best bet.  So what you'd want to do is set your StoreGeneratedPattern property of your key to None, and then point the Insert and Update methods to stored procedures in the DB that use SQL Server's MERGE feature, as described here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx

That's for doing exactly what you asked for as efficiently as possible.

That said... I think it's a bad design.  There's too many security and data integrity holes you open up, imo, by letting the duplicate key fallback silently to an update.  Your model should express clear and unambiguous intents, and your consuming code should use those intents appropriately or catch an exception and handle that case as appropriate.

Comment: This operation is storing data that may be delivered multiple times (redundant message transmissions). I don't think there are any security or integrity issues, but I do agree that clearly expressing intent is a Very Good Idea (tm).

I'll leave the code as it is because it sounds like it would increase the overall complexity by requiring stored procedures to be developed then indirectly called in a manner that wouldn't be immediately obvious looking only at the C# code snippet.

I didn't know the low-level SQL operations could be overridden. Thanks!

Comment: To me, though, reduntant transmissions means the same thing sent multiple times; that strikes me as a case where you'd want to discard the message if it's already in the db, not run an update.  So the simplest answer would be to just let the key check fail, and discard the exception (or possibly log it or whatever).  Why make an extra round-trip to see if it's already there?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. FYI, what's actually happening is a fixed-size block of data is being delivered containing multiple records of "logged" data. Some of these records correspond to times in the future and these records are arbitrarily set to zero. Zero it also a valid logged value, and there may be clock-differences between sender and receiver. When a repeat message is received, not all the records are redundant, but it's not easy to know which are and which aren't. The simplest solution is to update all the matching records with the latest information.

Answer (score 0):

I personally found your code to be fairly simple and readable. I think it fairly well describes what you're trying to do, and future programmers will understand how your data model works when they look at it.

If you run into significant efficiency issues with this, you can set up your database to automatically insert values when they're not found. But this tends to make your model behave "magically," so if efficiency is secondary I would leave your code more-or-less as-is (maybe using JMarsh's suggestion to improve the likelihood that you won't have to make a database roundtrip).

Comment: Many thanks for your comments on my code. I agree that magic code is a bad thing, which is why on balance, I've decided to leave the code as it is. If efficiency does become an issue, I'll revisit it.